# Laravel session not retained after redirect to another website

Tags: laravel-4

Before laravel upgrade, I can store some data into session and retrieve it after the 3rd party payment is completed.

Order Item -> 3rd party Payment website -> Complete/Fail

After the new update, once I go to the payment website and comeback, the session data gone.

P/S: Someone is asking the same question on the laravel forum but no answer.
http://laravel.io/forum/04-14-2014-session-data-reset-after-payment-from-redirect-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding www into the redirected domain, seems like www.example.com and example.com are using the different sessions.